# AJAX call on JavaScript applied to Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to limit my region's show page to only display locations that match the region that's being displayed. So if Illinois is the page being present then only cities in Illinois should be present and nothing else.

My region's show page has the following:

```
<div class="container-fluid>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="banner" id="region-banner>
  </div>
  <div class="location-container container">
     <h3><%= @region.name %> </h3>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<script>document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', app.regions);</script>
```

region-banner is then being used in my region.js that pulls up the following:

```
app.regions = () => {
  function init() {
   startGoogleMap();
   let tabs = document.querySelectorAll("a.tab");
    for (let tab of tabs) {
        tab.addEventListener("click", tabClicked);
    }
    document
        .querySelector("#region-select_")
        .addEventListener("change", selectClicked);
}
let startGoogleMap = () => {
    let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("region-banner"), {
        zoom: 7,
        // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        gestureHandling: "cooperative",
        styles: mapStyle
    });
    const chicago = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(39.900705, -86.061112),
        map: map,
        region: "Illinois",
        icon: "/marker.png",
        title: "Chicago"
    });

    const baltimore = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(39.332629, -76.746407),
        map: map,
        region: "Maryland"
        icon: "/marker.png",
        title: "Baltimore"
    });
    let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    bounds.extend(cedar.position);
    bounds.extend(baltimore.position);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  };
 return init();
};
```

So how do I restrict the page based on reading through the regions and matching against @region.name?